# Multiple view model binding error: knocout js

Tags: knockout.js

Am just trying to fiddle with the samples provided by knockout and trying to bind two view models, Here is the code, am having issues with the second view model:

```
    <div class='liveExample1'>   
      <p>First name: <input data-bind='value: firstName' /></p> 
      <p>Last name: <input data-bind='value: lastName' /></p> 
      <h2>Hello, <span data-bind='text: fullName'> </span>!</h2>  
   </div>

    <div class='liveExample'> 

    <form data-bind="submit: addItem">
        New item:
        <input data-bind='value: itemToAdd, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' />
        <button type="submit" data-bind="enable: itemToAdd().length > 0">Add</button>
        <p>Your items:</p>
        <select multiple="multiple" width="50" data-bind="options: items"> </select>
    </form>

    </div>
```

and my view model is :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Here's my data model
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var ViewModel = function (first, last) {
                this.firstName = ko.observable(first);
                this.lastName = ko.observable(last);

                this.fullName = ko.computed(function () {
                    // Knockout tracks dependencies automatically. It knows that fullName depends on firstName and lastName, because these get called when evaluating fullName.
                    return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
                }, this);
            };


            ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Planet", "Earth"), $("#liveExample1")[0]); // This makes Knockout get to work?



    var SimpleListModel = function(items) {
        this.items = ko.observableArray(items);
        this.itemToAdd = ko.observable("");
        this.addItem = function() {
            if (this.itemToAdd() != "") {
                this.items.push(this.itemToAdd()); // Adds the item. Writing to the "items" observableArray causes any associated UI to update.
                this.itemToAdd(""); // Clears the text box, because it's bound to the "itemToAdd" observable
            }
        }.bind(this);  // Ensure that "this" is always this view model
    };

    ko.applyBindings(new SimpleListModel(["Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma"]), $("#liveExample")[0]); 


        });
```

How do I resolve, **"this"** issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another variable for **"this"** view model

```
var self = this;
```

and use `self` variable instade of `this`
Also you can use `data-bind="with : viewModel"` for each model.
Here you code is workable 
[You code](http://jsfiddle.net/DCuYB/)